# Thermocouple short-circuit detection

Tags: short-circuit, detection, thermocouple

I'm trying to figure out how to detect a shorted K-type thermocouple (between the wires, not a wire to GND or Vcc.) I would define a short as thermocouple resistance < 0.1 ohm as opposed to 1 ohm or more (rises with temperature) without a short. I have thought of two ways:

1. In normal operation the thermocouple has a low bias current (a 10Mohm resistor thermocouple+ to Vcc, a 10Mohm resistor thermocouple+ to GND.)  I could periodically run a much higher current through the thermocouple and see if there is a significant voltage drop across the thermocouple.
2. Run an additional AC current through the thermocouple constantly. After appropriate filtering, the AC voltage across the thermocouple would be related to its resistance. By making the DC and AC voltages separate I could avoid the timing complexity of method 1.

Are any of these methods used or do you see a catch in either? Are there better methods?

I have read somewhere that reflections are used to detect a short in a thermocouple but can't find anything on this.

All of the above assumes a short at the thermocouple output. What happens if the two wires get shorted out say a few centimeters from the hot junction? Would the temperature at this point be measured? Is this detectable at all? [see here](https://www.instrumentationtoolbox.com/2011/01/sensors-used-in-industrial.html)

Comment: As short on two thermocouples should be "unlikely"  at the same time ... use of "two" thermocouples at the "same" place should be "interesting" ...

Answer (score 1):

It’s very difficult to detect a shorted thermocouple since the thermocouple itself is essentially two wires shorted at the tip. If the resistance changes substantially that is one possibility. But the thermocouple resistance may change for other reasons such as the temperature of the lead wire and the contact resistance of connectors.

In the case of a controller you may be able to indirectly detect that something is wrong if the measured temperature does not respond as expected to the controller output. For example, if heat has been turned in full for a period of time and the measured variable has not changed much.

If the wires are shorted back of the intended junction then the measured temperature will be closer to the temperature at the short, but it depends on the resistances involved, especially the short resistance. In something like a furnace or kiln application that could cause the heat to never turn off.

Open detection is easy and is standard.

Comment: Measuring thermocouple resistance poses an interesting problem (never attempted). The built-in voltage offset likely makes an ohmmeter reading dubious. Could two measurements with leads reversed (averaged) make more sense?

Comment: @glen_geek Sure, or just measure the change with and without test current.

Answer (score 0):

EE&O ...  Maple sheet.

Here is a "mean" (example) of calculating what one wants.
There is only the need for a "switched" resistor and some "calculation".
This gives quasi ... the "true" values of internal resistor (R1 or R13) and V1

[image]

[image]